# Why is my expression matching something that clearly doesn't meet the expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, match

I'm using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to match the pattern, numbers, an arbitrary number of spaces, and a potential "+" at the end.  So I wrote

```
2.3.0 :013 > /\d+\s*\+?/.match("40+")
 => #<MatchData "40+">
```

However, this is also matching

```
2.3.0 :012 > /\d+\s*\+?/.match("40-50")
 => #<MatchData "40">
```

What gives?  The string "40-50" doesn't match the expression provided, but clearly I'm not doing something right in my regex.

Comment: `/(^\d+\s*\+?$)/`

Comment: You forgot to put "start of string"/"end of string" markers into your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to match only the full string, use the `\A` and `\z` markers. Like this:

```
/\A\d+\s*\+\z$/.match("40-50")
```

This will force the regular expression to match only if the full string match it.

Otherwise, the way you have it now, it will stop as soon as it find a match anywhere in your string.

`\d+` means one digit or more.

`\s*` means an optional space.

`\+?` means an optional + sign

So `40` does match those conditions.

Comment: To match the full __string__ one must use `\A` / `\z`, not ^/$.

Comment: Yes, your right Sergio, my bad. The ^/$ will find a match if your string is multiline while \A/\Z wont.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem :)

Comment: btw, it's better to use `\z`, not `\Z`

Answer (score 0):

### The `?` Quantifier is Your Problem

You want the following instead:

```
/\d+\s*\+/.match("40-50")
```

If you use `\+?` instead of `\+` without a quantifier, the question mark modifies the statement to mean "zero or one of the preceding atoms." With the quantifier, `40-50` matches since it has zero `+` characters in the string.

Comment: Plus sign is optional